# How to make a generic trigger to set the audit fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, audit, sql-server-2016

I want to automatically set the audit fields (UpdatedBy/UpdatedOn) on my tables.  To that end, I have a trigger on every table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_AsyncMessage_Upd] ON [dbo].[AsyncMessage] AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE m
    SET 
       m.UpdatedOn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
      ,m.UpdatedBy = SUSER_SNAME()
    FROM dbo.AsyncMessage m
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
    ON m.AsyncMessageID = i.AsyncMessageID

END
```

However, I'd rather not have to write a trigger for every single table. Is there a way to tell SQL Server to auto set them for me?  Or is there a way to have a single trigger to cover all tables?

Comment: Nothing inbuilt. You could generate the required statements programmatically though.

Comment: You can set same trigger for several tables with dynamic sql

Comment: Dos every user use a different username? are you using Win-Auth or SQL Server users?

Comment: @FLICKER I am using SQL Server.  Yes, every user has a different user name.

Comment: @tungula How do I get a trigger that covers multiple tables?

Comment: I don't know, but you can easily add separate trigger for all table with dynamic sql(of course if you many tables and if you need it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.  Copy the output of this, and check it over before you run it.  This only works if the table has a primary key, and has the updatedby and updatedon columns.

```
SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER tr_'+TABLE_NAME+'_Update ON '+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME+' 
        AFTER UPDATE
        AS
        BEGIN
            UPDATE T SET UPDATEDBY=SYSTEM_USER, UPDATEDON=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM '+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME+' T
            JOIN inserted I ON T.'+COLUMN_NAME+'=I.'+COLUMN_NAME+'
        END'

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + CONSTRAINT_NAME), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME='UpdatedOn' AND CU.TABLE_NAME=C.TABLE_NAME)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2 WHERE C2.COLUMN_NAME='UpdatedBy' AND CU.TABLE_NAME=C2.TABLE_NAME)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know...  I've done this.  It just doesn't smell right to me - to have a trigger for every single table that does the same thing.  Anyway, seeing how there is no other viable option - I am marking this answer as the solution.

Comment: @AngryHacker; If you turn this code into a stored procedure, you can call this every time you create a table. If you then create a SQL Agent job that runs this code every minute, then all of your tables will have a trigger, except the very few tables you forget, and then only for one minute.

Answer (score 1):

Sql is not C#, don't try to treat it as if it was.  What is good practice in C# is not necessarily a good practice in SQL. SQL is declaractive, and generally has limited ability to modify multiple tables at the same time.

Simply write the trigger once per table, if you are doing this for a lot of tables, then write something that writes the trigger for you, and then run the results.